# Proxy tester with threading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I have written a simple proxy checker in Python. I have a one question - how to get speed up it? I trying to use queue and threading, but it didn't work.
If it is possible use threading lib

Code:

```
import socks

red = "\033[1;31m"
green = "\033[1;32m"
yellow = "\033[1;33m"
blue = "\033[1;34m"
defaultcolor = "\033[0m"

linesinfile = len(open('proxy.txt', 'rU').readlines())

def proxygff():
    global fp
    with open('proxy.txt') as fp:
        pff = fp.readline()
        global cnt
        cnt = 1
        while pff:
            global PROXYIP, PROXYPORT
            PROXYIP, PROXYPORT = pff.split(":")
            pff = fp.readline()
            cnt = cnt + 1
            checkmain()


def savetofile(proxy):
    with open("proxywork.txt", 'a') as file:
        file.write(proxy)


def checkmain():
    try:
        socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.SOCKS5, str(PROXYIP), int(PROXYPORT))
        s = socks.socksocket()
        s.settimeout(1)
        s.connect(("google.com", 80))
        print blue + "Proxy working! " + green + str(cnt) + defaultcolor + "/" + green + str(linesinfile)
        proxy = PROXYIP + ":" + PROXYPORT
        savetofile(proxy)
        s.close()
    except:
        print red + "Proxy not working! " + green + str(cnt) + defaultcolor + "/" + green + str(linesinfile)


proxygff()
```

Written in Python 2.7

Comment: Quoting Michael Jackson on optimization: "Rule 1: Don't do it.
Rule 2 (for experts only). Don't do it yet - that is, not until you have a perfectly clear and unoptimized solution." -- https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Michael_A._Jackson If you must go ahead with optimizing, get a profiler first and measure where your code spends its time.

Answer (score 0):

Python's multithreading will help you only when you creating a connection to `google.com` and waiting a response from them. Python interpreter runs only one thread at time due to [GIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_interpreter_lock). You can do the same things (avoid IO waitings) with asyncio module (Python >= 3.4). And you have to do rewrite your code because you set up default proxy globally `socks.setdefaultproxy` for all opening sockets.